# Unable to record webcam video in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webcam, webrtc

When I try and record webcam video using an instance of LocalMediaStream as per the WebRTC spec, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<LocalMediaStream> has no method 'record'
```

I have tried stable/beta/dev & canary builds of Google Chrome.

Is it currently possible to record webcam video using any currently available version of Google Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

I have since confirmed that it is currently not possible to record webcam video using any currently available version of Google Chrome.